# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'type'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Im gettin this error but i dont know what it is. I've looked for the answer but none can answer main or maybe im just missing something. Here my code:

```
Connection db = new Connection();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewBag.query = from input in db.field
                            where input.ID_FIELD == 1
                            select new {
                                type = input.FIELD_TYPE 
                            };


            return View();
        }
```

and the view side

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.query)
        { 
                @item.type//error here: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'type', why???
        }
```

And if i make a simple select with where clause, work ok
   public ActionResult Index()
            {

```
            ViewBag.query = from input in db.field
                            where input.ID_FIELD == 1
                            select input.FIELD_TYPE;


            return View();
        }
```

What could be my problem? I've seem many toturials doing the same and works great like this one i did just now:
    int[] number = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

```
            var query = from num in number
                        let x = num + num + num
                        select new {avg = x};

               foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.avg);

            }
```

Everything is ok here. Why could be the problem??

Comment: `ViewBag.query` is a list of `FIELD_TYPE`, so `item` = `FIELD_TYPE` and it does not have a property called `type`. You just need to do @item and that's the value you need.

Comment: this worked but it printed out : {type = Text}. Why?

Comment: Because you are not printing out the value but a `Type`. I just saw a new answer posted. Look at P.Brian's answer it will push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return an anonymous type from a method.  Instead, create a new type and return that type.

For example:

```
ViewBag.query = from input in db.field
                            where input.ID_FIELD == 1
                            select new MyType() {
                                someField = input.FIELD_TYPE 
                            };

public class MyType
{
  public int someField {get;set;}//compatible with whatever type FIELD_TYPE is.
}
```

Comment: It there another way to that without the need of creating another class?? Btw, it worked great!!

Comment: @user2195741 - The type generated by the compiler is not accessible to the user.  For this reason, I don't think there's a different way to achieve your goal when returning the type.  However, there's almost always more than one way to skin a cat so it wouldn't surprise me to find out other things are possible (some clever use of dynamic perhaps?).  This is what I do in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

In your Last Example you are Not using 'item.type'. Apart from that, System.Object does Not contain a property 'type'. You can use 'GetType()', though.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ViewBag is `dynamic`, but the *anonymous object* you're storing in it is not, so the compiler cannot access its properties directly.  You could just store a collection of values in the ViewBag property rather then the whole query:

```
Connection db = new Connection();
public ActionResult Index()
{

    ViewBag.types = from input in db.field
                    where input.ID_FIELD == 1
                    select input.FIELD_TYPE;

    return View();
}
```

and then

```
@foreach (var type in ViewBag.types)
{ 
    @type
}
```